# Infopath forms migration to Office 365 - Things to consider

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

I'm working with a client who are considering moving to Office 365 from SP 2007. They are using Infopath forms in SP 2007 which uses data connection that connects to the backend SQL Server (for example populating some drop down values)

In this scenario,

1. what are the things I need to consider to migrate the forms to Office 365.
2. How to redesign the infopath form so that it can access data from on-prem SQL Server.
3. How can I connect to an on-prem SQL data from Infopath? Is it via web service that can be accessible via internet?